# Apache Tika MP4 metadata keys

Tags: apache, apache-tika, mp4parser

I'm using Apache Tika v 1.4 to parse video files in the following way.

```
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
String content = new Tika().parseToString(file.getInputStream(), metadata);
metadata.get(KEY)
```

The problem is that I don't know which keys to use in some cases. For example the MP4 keys:
Duration.
Frame Rate.

Where key I find these keys?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try reading the [metadata javadocs](https://tika.apache.org/1.4/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/Metadata.html) eg [XMPDM](https://tika.apache.org/1.4/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/XMPDM.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

`metadata.names()` method return an array of the names contained in the metadata.

So we can use this method to get the keys.